# Can't print values of a 2d matrix using pointers

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, 2d

im having some troubles using pointers. Im trying to fill this 2D matrix but i can't printf their values.. can you please take a look and give me a hint.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define L1  3
#define C1  2

#define L2  4
#define C2  3

void write(int *p, int n_lin, int n_col){

int i,j;


    for(i=0;i<n_lin;i++){
        for(j=0;j<n_col;j++){
            printf("%d",*p[i][j]);  // <- Can't make it work :(
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
void main(){


int *p=NULL;
int mat1[L1][C1] = {{1,2}, {3,4}, {5,6}};

int mat2[L2][C2] = {{1,2,3}, {4,5,6}, {7,8,9}, {10,11,12}};

printf("Matriz 1:\n");
write(*mat1, L1, C1);

printf("\nMatriz 2:\n");
write(*mat2, L2, C2);

system("pause");
}
```

thanks.

Comment: `mat1` and `mat2` are of type `int**` not `int*`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a 2D array with

```
int mat1[L1][L2];
```

Your `mat1` is of type `int**`.

You must therefore change the way your function is called:

```
void write(int **p, int n_lin, int n_col){ // <- changed this
int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<n_lin;i++){
        for(j=0;j<n_col;j++){
            printf("%d",p[i][j]);  // <- Changed this! :)
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

and call it with

```
write(mat1, L1, C1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your for loop should be:

```
for(i=0;i<n_lin;i++){
    for(j=0;j<n_col;j++){
        printf("%d",p[i][j]);  // *p[i][j] should be p[i][j]
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: It doesen't work. gives this error on the second brackets IntelliSense: expression must have pointer-to-object

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the print statement to :

```
printf("%d",*( p + i*n_lin + j));
```

Other than that, there are a few more issues.

---

In the function definition, try using

```
void write(int p[][], int n_lin, int n_col){
```

Then using ,

```
printf("%d",p[i][j]));
```

And calling it with,

```
write(mat1, L1, C1);
```

Comment: that didn't work but ive already realized how to solve it! Just with            printf("%d",*(p++));    Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

You can create your write function like this:

```
template <int n_lin,int n_col>
void write(const int (&p)[n_lin][n_col])
{

    int i,j;

    for(i=0;i<n_lin;i++) {
        for(j=0;j<n_col;j++) {
            printf("%d ",p[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

and then just call

```
write(mat1);
write(mat2);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is one important aspect about pointers and arrays :-

```
One dimension  ---     a[i]  = *(a+i)
Two dimension  ---     a[i][j] = *(*(a+i)+j)   and so on...
```

Both are equivalent.... So now I believe you can figure out what the issue is :-)